# Can I globally turn off PyCharm wanting to handle my version control?

Tags: pycharm

I'd prefer not to have to unset the git handling on every project, is there a global config somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable plug-ins for specific version control systems in File¦Settings¦Plugins.